# Joining Two Tables with Different Data types MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to experiment with joining different data types from different tables. I thought I had the syntax correct but apparently I must be doing something wrong.

The syntax error says type mismatch in expression so I am sure I am not correctly converting the data types

Here is my join

```
SELECT CLng([Inventory].ItemID) AS [Item#],
Sum([Invoice].Quantity) AS [Order QTY] 
FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Inventory] ON [Invoice].ItemID = CLng([Inventory].ItemID)
WHERE ((([Invoice].OrderNumber) BETWEEN 1 And 23))
GROUP BY CLng([Inventory].ItemID);
```

Comment: which are the different data types ??

Comment: @scaisEdge Inventory.ItemID is String and Invoice.ItemID is number

Comment: Why don't you convert Inventory.ItemID to LongInt?

Comment: @Andre is that a thing?

Comment: Sorry, that was kinda vague. If `Inventory.ItemID` is actually a number, but stored in the table as text, you should change it in the table design to number (Long Integer). Design flaws like that tend to come back and bite you when you don't expect it, even if you have a workaround for now.

Comment: @Andre  Yeah I understand the simplicity of design but I know for a fact that I'll need to work with bad design from time to time and was just looking to practice/exercise on something that would be a pain in the ass in the future. Its more along the lines of gaining knowledge and experience for when I eventually come head to head with BS like this lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why where inside () ?  try remove   and convert number to str

```
 SELECT CLng([Inventory].ItemID) AS [Item#],
 Sum([Invoice].Quantity) AS [Order QTY] 
 FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Inventory] ON  Str ( [Invoice].ItemID)  =  [Inventory].ItemID
 WHERE [Invoice].OrderNumber) BETWEEN 1 And 23
 GROUP BY CLng([Inventory].ItemID);
```

or

```
  SELECT CLng([Inventory].ItemID) AS [Item#],
 Sum([Invoice].Quantity) AS [Order QTY] 
 FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Inventory] ON CLng( Str ( [Invoice].ItemID))  = CLng( [Inventory].ItemID)
 WHERE [Invoice].OrderNumber) BETWEEN 1 And 23
 GROUP BY CLng([Inventory].ItemID);
```

Comment: Still type mismatch, even though I did try this before. I got used to the extra parenthesis due to access adds them in queries sometimes.

Comment: When comparing ItemID fields , you convert one of them using CLng but not the other . Can u try using  ... JOIN [Inventory] ON CLng( [Invoice].ItemID) = CLng([Inventory].ItemID)

Comment: @x82  i have convertend the number in string and the string ([Inventory].ItemID) is not converted with CLng

Comment: @scaisEdge still presents a type mismatch error, though I didnt think to try converting the number to a string though.

Comment: I thought its a numeric field. But still looks like you are comparing a varchar field to a Long int ?

Comment: I have added also a select with both str converted in CLng

Comment: @scaisEdge converting the number to a string and then back to a number did the trick